# ActiveRecord return objects uniq given an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I return an ActiveRecord relation of objects which do not repeat a given attribute (for example title).

So, if in my DB I have:

```
Id Title
1   foo
2   bar
3   foo
```

I would just recieve object with id 1 and object with id 2.

Comment: Why is the record with id=1 chosen over the record with id=3? Should the one chosen always be the one with the lowest id?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ActiveRecord relation or model e.g. `Book` maybe you can use a group query method.

```
Book.group(:name)
```

From: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group

I hope that I have you understood right and it helps.